# Grails getting results back from the database

Tags: grails

I need to get the results of a database search to print out on a gsp page. I currently have this

```
<h1>Invoices</h1>
       <g:each in="${dueInvoices}" var="di">
        <li>${di}</li>
        </g:each>
```

All I get back when I load the page

Invoices invoicetest.Invoices

I have also tried naming each column in a database inside an HTML table and still just get the same thing back

My groovy code to make this work is

```
def dueInvoices(){
        def today = new Date()
        def invoices = Invoices.findAllByDueDateLessThan(today + 6)
        render(view: "dueInvoices", model: [dueInvoices : Invoices ])
```

This code is used to find all invoices that are due in the next 6 days

Answer (score 3):

In the model, you are passing down the class instead of your list of instances:

```
def invoices = Invoices.findAllByDueDateLessThan(today + 6)
render(view: "dueInvoices", model: [dueInvoices : invoices ])
```